# Vue-qrcode-reader not working on Android device (Quasar framework + cordova)

Tags: cordova, android-camera, quasar-framework

In my quasar app, I added [vue-qrcode-reader](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader) which is working fine in a browser. I get prompted to give permission to use the webcam whereafter I'm able to scan a QR code.

However, after building the apk using cordova and running it on my android device, nothing happens. Also I don't get prompted for camera permission.

I tried adding the following code to cordova's config.xml:

```
<config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</config-file>
```

... but it still doesn't prompt me and no camera window appears.

Am I'm missing something? I can't find many docs about this and I'm quite new to app development. Really have no idea on how to solve this or even debug this.

Comment: I faced this problem as well .. the only option i had is to use the Cordova Barcode scanner plugin ..  check this tutorial .... [Use Quasar to build an Android app - QR CODE APP](https://www.kevin7.net/post_detail/use-quasar-to-build-an-android-app)...
It seems like the vue-qrcode doesn't work in quasar as someone stated this in GitHub issues